# Match a route with a route pattern

Tags: c#, nancy

I want to use `DefaultRoutePatternMatcher` to check if a route has a match in a pattern:

```
DefaultRoutePatternMatcher m = new DefaultRoutePatternMatcher();
m.Match("/dashboard/rest/order/2247/", 
     "/dashboard/rest/order/{id}/", new List<string>(), Context);
```

I'd say this should give `IsMatch` is `true`, but it isn't.

How can I use the `DefaultRoutePatternMatcher` in Nancy?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want to use this directly, but... this works

```
        var extractor = new DefaultRouteSegmentExtractor();
        var segments = extractor.Extract("/dashboard/rest/order/{id}/");

        DefaultRoutePatternMatcher m = new DefaultRoutePatternMatcher();
        var result = m.Match("/dashboard/rest/order/2247/",
             "/dashboard/rest/order/{id}/", segments, new NancyContext());

        Assert.Equal(true, result.IsMatch);
```